# Trigger ApplicationListener before WebServer starts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a short lived process to read a simple file from a classpath into a memory, I chose `ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>` to let spring trigger a task:

```
@Component
@Priority(1)
class MyLoader implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
    doStuff();
  }

}
```

I realised not that few HTTP requests that I offer in this app depend on that data in memory. How can I force `MyLoader` class to execute before Web Server is ready to serve request? I have no idea how to define that dependency?

Answer (score 0):

You should listen for an event before the `ApplicationReadyEvent`, because it is the final one, marking that the application is ready to serve requests.

For example, you can listen to `ApplicationStartingEvent`. See a list of the available ApplicationEvents [here](https://www.javapedia.net/Spring-Boot/2927).

Comment: Is there any way to clearly set that dependency, I can't even find any information what event is triggered after servlet container is up.